# How to return null QDomElement?

Tags: qt5, qdomdocument

Qt XML manipulation is kind of weird - although the QDomElement objects refer to their representations in document, they are not pointers.

To indicate *"null"* element, `isNull` method is used. How do I create `QDomElement` that returns `true` on `isNull`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QDomElement` inherits `QDomNode`. The documentation states:

> bool QDomNode::isNull() const
>
> Returns true if this node is null (i.e. if it has no type or
>   contents); otherwise returns false.

and also

> QDomNode::QDomNode()
>
> Constructs a null node.

In your example you only need to return `QDomElement()` as a null node.

Comment: I was thinking about something more practical. I wrote a method to find nodes based on criteria. To stick with Qt convention, I wanted to return null node if nothing is found.

Comment: Answer fixed. I did not understand your question. It sounds like you ask how to manipulate nodes and how any of them can be null.